# Textfields aren't stretching when in same Grid with react-select Select

Tags: material-ui, react-select

This is a recent issue and this only happens on Chrome (Version 76.0.3809.132).  I've got a real simple dialog that contains a material ui (v4.3.3) Grid, some TextFields and 2 react-select(v3.0.4) Select boxes.  The container is setup with justify flex-start and alignItems stretch.  The input controls are simply wrapped up in Grid items all with fullWidth set on them.  The issue I'm seeing is that on render, the TextFields don't stretch the entire width of the Grid while the Selects do.  Here's where it gets interesting, if I tab cycle focus through the components the TextFields will snap to full width as soon as the react-select Select component gets focus, this also occurs if I just click into the react-select Select component.  If I shift-tab cycle back to the TextFields, they snap back to their original stunted width.

If I remove the Selects from the Grid, the TextFields stretch the width of the container as expected.  I've removed all custom styling from the react-select Select and it still exhibits the same behavior (TextFields displaying not at full width).  I also tried a separate 3rd party react wrapper around react-select, react-select-material-ui, and it still exhibits the same behavior.

```
        <Grid
          container
          direction="column"
          justify="flex-start"
          alignItems="stretch"
        >
          <Grid item>
            <Select ... />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <TextField ... />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <TextField ... />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <TextField ... />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Select ... />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

As mentioned, this was working as expected until recently and only happens in Chrome.  My expectation is that the TextFields will render the full width of the container consistently.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Chrome (Version 77.0.3865.75) appears to have fixed a rendering issue.  Things are rendering as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to pass **fullWidth** property to the TextField/Select.

fullWidth is **boolean** type.

By default it is true.

See the example below:

Note: Make sure to import the required fields.

```
<Grid
      container
      direction="column"
      justify="flex-start"
      alignItems="stretch"
    >
      <Grid item sm={12} md={6}>
        <TextField fullWidth />
      </Grid>
<Grid item sm={12} md={6}>
<FormControl fullWidth>
  <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Select option</InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
    id="demo-simple-select"
    value={age}
    label="Age"
    onChange={handleChange}
  >
    <MenuItem value='Opt 1>Opt 1</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value='Opt 2'>Opt 2</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</FormControl>
</Grid>
 </Grid>
```